# React js reducer logical condition

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks, conditional-statements

Below code filter option is used. I know the filter method of how it works. Here I doubt the logical statement of 'DELETE_NOTE'. note.id will hold the id number 0,1,2... My doubt is what action.payload is doing with the condition. Will it hold the number like id 1,2,3. Please clear it.

```
export default function reducer(state, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
     case 'SET_CURRENT_NOTE':
         return {
             ...state,
             currentNote: action.payload
         }
         case 'DELETE_NOTE':
           const deleteNotes = state.notes.filter(
               note => note.id !== action.payload
           )
           return {
               state,
               notes: deleteNotes
           }
     default:
         return state;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Deleting the Note, You will be dispatching `DELETE_NOTE` action with `note Id` as payload shown below.

`dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_NOTE', payload: 3});`  - here payload is nothing but the id of the note to be deleted.

In the reducer function, filter all the notes in the state except the deleted note Id, and returning the updated state.

```
case 'DELETE_NOTE':
           const deleteNotes = state.notes.filter(
               note => note.id !== action.payload // here payload will be 3
           )
           return {
               ...state,
               notes: deleteNotes
           }
```